# What is the platform underneath the map?

Tags: hello-neighbor

When escaping the map and jumping off, you can find a blackish rectangular prism underneath.

What is this platform used for?

Comment: I've seen speculation that it's where the basement is going to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not the basement.

As I found out, it's actually the dream where you are in a circus and you have the option to either hide under the bed or in the wardrobe before the neighbor (who is crying) tries to find you.

I learnt this from a video, but I cannot find the exact one. I'll update this when I find the exact one.

There is, of course, a reason why it's **NOT** the basement:

> **Pre-Alpha:** When the door to the basement is opened, nothing is beyond it.
>  **Alpha 1:** When the door is opened, it doesn't lead you to the basement. Instead, there is a cutscene when the Neighbor closes the door and buries you alive.
>  **Alpha 2:** When you enter the basement, it leads you to another worldspace, due to a cut.
>  **Alpha3:** When you enter the door, it actually leads you to a flashback.

Comment: This is correct.